# How to create one line plot per color series in Observable Plot?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, observablehq, observable-plot

**Description:**

I am playing around with [Observable Plot](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/plot) an really like how easy it is to set up simple plots.

Now I have a little "more advanced" chart that I want to plot and need help.

In my data, I have multiple `temp` (temperature) readings recorded at a certain `timestamp`.
Each reading comes from a `sensor`, and each `sensor` is attached to a certain `device` (multiple sensors (e.g., 1-3) can be attached to a single device (e.g., 2)).
Thus, one data point might look like the following (see bottom script for a full [minimal workabel example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)):

```
{
  timestamp: 1,
  device: 1,
  sensor: 1,
  temp: 20
}
```

Currently, I [*dot plot*](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/plot-dot?collection=@observablehq/plot) this data, *facet* it based on the sensor, and give a color the each `(device, sensor)` pair series (just run below snippet to get a better feeling).

**Problem:**

I now would like to connect all dots of the same color with a black line.
I marked the problematic line with `// HERE I NEED HELP` in the snippet.
I assume that I somehow have to group `data` based on `device` and `sensor` to achieve a similar grouping to the color, but I sadly have no idea how to achieve this and hope that you can help!

```js
const plotTestTemperatures = function(data) {
  const div = document.getElementById('temp-chart-test')
  div.appendChild(Plot.plot({
    color: {
      type: "ordinal",
      scheme: "category10",
      legend: true
    },
    facet: { data: data, x: "device", grid: true,}, 
    grid: true,
    marks: [
      Plot.frame(),
      Plot.dot(data, {x: "timestamp", y: "temp", r: 4, opacity: 0.8, fill: d => `Sensor ${d.sensor} of device ${d.device}` }),
      // HERE I NEED HELP
      // does not yet work, connects all dots independent of color
      // Plot.line(data, {x: "timestamp", y: "temp", opacity: 0.8, stroke: "black" })
    ],              
  }));
}

// call with test data
plotTestTemperatures([
  {
    timestamp: 1,
    device: 1,
    sensor: 1,
    temp: 20
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2,
    device: 1,
    sensor: 1,
    temp: 21
  },
  {
    timestamp: 3,
    device: 1,
    sensor: 1,
    temp: 22
  },
  {
    timestamp: 1,
    device: 1,
    sensor: 2,
    temp: 20.1
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2,
    device: 1,
    sensor: 2,
    temp: 21.3
  },
  {
    timestamp: 3,
    device: 1,
    sensor: 2,
    temp: 22.5
  },
  {
    timestamp: 1,
    device: 2,
    sensor: 1,
    temp: 18
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2,
    device: 2,
    sensor: 1,
    temp: 19
  },
  {
    timestamp: 3,
    device: 2,
    sensor: 1,
    temp: 20
  },
  {
    timestamp: 1,
    device: 2,
    sensor: 2,
    temp: 17.8
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2,
    device: 2,
    sensor: 2,
    temp: 19.1
  },
  {
    timestamp: 3,
    device: 2,
    sensor: 2,
    temp: 20.1
  },
])
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta name=”robots” content=”noindex”>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home Automation</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/plot@0.4"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>Home Automation</h1>
        <div id="temp-chart-test"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(*cross-posted to the [ObservableHQ forum](https://talk.observablehq.com/t/how-to-create-one-line-plot-per-color-series-in-observable-plot)*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is

```js
z: (d) => `Sensor ${d.sensor} of device ${d.device}`,
```

Comment: Thank you, that made it work! Do you have more information on this `z`, a link maybe?

Comment: [Link to answer in Observable HQ forum](https://talk.observablehq.com/t/how-to-create-one-line-plot-per-color-series-in-observable-plot/6174/4)